Vite Moment locale ignore
With webpack we used IgnorePlugin like this
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
        resourceRegExp: /^\.\/locale$/,
        contextRegExp: /moment$/
      })
    ]
  }
}

how can I achieve this with vite
I don't need moment extra locales on my bundle

Since Vite uses Rollup under the hood, you could try something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-ignore
